# Getting value from getWidthForSizeColsToFit()

Tags: ag-grid

Can I please somehow get width from this function? I can see that GridPanel.prototype.sizeColumnsToFit do it like this:

```
var availableWidth = this.getWidthForSizeColsToFit();
```

But how can I myself get the availableWidth so I can use it like this (for example):

```
gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(SomethingcolumnDefs);    
gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnWidth('something1', 0.4 * availableWidth, finished=true);
gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnWidth(something2', 0.3 * availableWidth, finished=true);
gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnWidth('something3', 0.2 * availableWidth, finished=true);
gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnWidth('something4', 0.1 * availableWidth, finished=true);
```

I will be grateful if you can post this information.

EDIT:
This seems to be a problem of context. I tried things like:

```
var availableWidth = document.querySelector('#myGrid').getWidthForSizeColsToFit();
```

but all without success...

Answer (score 0):

use **suppressSizeToFit:true** in column property and mention the width,so when ag-grid call GridPanel.prototype.sizeColumnsToFit ,then it will not alter the width of column which is having property **suppressSizeToFit:true**,by default it is false.

example:

```
 {headerName: "Employee No", suppressSizeToFit:true,field: "employeeno", width: 250}
```